# Eclipse Keppler 64 on Ubuntu 12.04 Pydev Bookmark Menu disabled

Tags: eclipse, pydev, bookmarks

PyDev perspective is missing the Add Bookmark... option in the right click menu. The option is available via Edit Menu. What happened? Java Perspective and other text files allow the menu.
This worked a few days ago!?? To reproduce I just create a new file inside a brand new PyDev project. I right click....No Bookmark option!

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked in window > customize perspective > menu visibility > edit that 'add bookmark' is checked?

Still, if it's something you use regularly, you could bind the 'add bookmark' action to some binding and use it:

I.e.: Ctrl+Shift+L (twice), filter with 'add bookmark' and put a binding for it.

Comment: Thanks! my menu visibility has 'add bookmark' checked in PyDev. Still no option. I did add a key binding as suggested. Nice work-around. Thank again. I just Installed ShellEd in eclipse and turns on 'add bookmark' only bash scripts (groan). I wish there was a way to add and remove options in the right-click menu.

Comment: It doesn't work from the context menu (Pydev bug?), but it does work from the 'Edit' menu. Thanks for the tip.